# How to show that the logical equivalence relation, $\equiv$, is an equivalence relation on $F$

Tags: logic, equivalence-relations

Let $F$ denote the set of well-formed formulas over a set Prop of propositional variables. Show that the logical equivalence relation, $\equiv$, is an equivalence relation on $F$.

if I assume $\equiv$ is a relation $E$, then I can prove that for any well-formed formulas $P$,
$(P,P) \in E$ because $P \equiv P$, so $E$ is reﬂexive.

Is that a correct way to show reflexivity? And how should I show the Symmetry and Transitivity of $\equiv$, can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. If you [edit] the question to show us how you would start a proof and where you are stuck we may be able to help. To show symmetry, you'd start "suppose $A$ and $B$ are related. That means ..."

Comment: Thanks for reminder, I have edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: For symmetry, you need to show that for all wff, P, Q,  in Prop, If $P \equiv Q$, then $Q \equiv P$.  For transitivity, you need to show that for all P, Q, R in Prop, If $P\equiv Q$ and $Q\equiv R$, then $P \equiv R$.

Comment: You also need to make sure that you *show*, rather than just state, that the respective properties hold. For $P \equiv P$ this is trivial; for the other two you will need a bit of argumentation.

Comment: Are you attempting a formal proof? If so,what axioms are you starting with?

Answer (score 1):

To paraphrase the Wikipedia definition of logical equivalence (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence)statements: statements *p* and *q* are said to be **logically equivalent** if they are provable from each other under a set of axioms, or have the same truth value in every model.

- Reflexivity – Since *p* always has the same truth value as *p*
- Symmetry – Since each statement is provable from the other
- Transitivity – Since the application of successive proofs will provide the needed implication in one direction and symmetry will allow for the required proof in the opposite direction.